# Writing an object value in java

Tags: java

Hello I have question to my small program how I can print the value of `p1`? When I am using `p1.toString()` method this still shows me the address of an object I was searching in google some other ways and I still don't know how to do this. Here is the code:

```
public class Boss {
String name;

public Boss(String input) { // This is the constructor
    name = "Our Boss is also known as : " + input;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Boss p1 = new Boss("Super-Man");

    System.out.println(p1.toString());
}
```

Comment: What is `toString()`?

Comment: If you didn't override toString with your own code. It will use Object.toString() which will return the Object@[Location] you need to override toString.

Comment: `name` is not the "value" of the object. If you want to print the name, you can implement `toString`, or you can print `p1.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to override `toString()`

```
// Add this to Boss
public String toString() {
  return name;
}
```

Or (as you currently have your code),

```
// System.out.println(p1.toString());
System.out.println(p1.name);
```

You should probably add a `getName()` method to `Boss` as well,

```
 public String getName() {
   return name;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `toString` method to get the functionality that you are expecting.  Also I recommend setting the `String name` to `private` while you're at it.  If you need to provide access to the `String` then create a `get` method to return it.  This prevents someone from modifying it when they shouldn't have access.  Not providing an access modifier in `Java` defaults to `protected`.

```
public class Boss {
    private String name; // Change access modifier to private

    public Boss(String input) {
        name = "Our Boss is also known as : " + input;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){ // Override the toString method
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Boss p1 = new Boss("Super-Man");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `toString()` method in Object prints **class name @ hash code**. You can override `toString()` method in your class to print proper output.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
```

Sources:

1. http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/override-tostring-method-java-tips-example-code.html
2. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/